# Where does the Add Account information auto-populate from

Tags: macos

In **System Preferences**, under **Mail, Contacts & Calendars** if you add an account (Microsoft Exchange or GMail) a few of the fields are auto populated (ie Name and email address).

Where is this information pulled from?

I suspect it is from the information entered when you register the Mac on first boot. Can someone please confirm this?

Also, is there an easy way to modify this information so it doesn't autofill with the incorrect name/email?

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS X version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a contact in Contacts.app which has a little head and shoulders silhouette next to it in the list and a grey bar with "me" across the picture.

I think you are right that this is created when you first started using the computer.

Comment: Interestingly on my Mac I didn't have a "Me" contact in Contacts but it still pulled my correct name from somewhere. 

However, I think that clears up the issue I described above.

Comment: Yes, this is true. When you set up your Mac there is an entry made in the Adressbook.app / Contacts.app which is then linked to your login name and picture. It is somehow magically connected even if the "me" badge is not associated. Have seen both version on different Macs and OS X versions.